# Azure Policy reports Linux VM as complaint for Hybrid Benefit

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-policy

I have created a policy for reporting Azure Hybrid benefit and it works well for the Windows machines but the issue is, it's showing complaint for Linux as well which is creating confusion. Is it possible to exclude or not to evaluate and report Linux machines as complaint?

```json
{
  "mode": "All",
  "policyRule": {
    "if": {
      "allOf": [
        {
          "field": "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/storageProfile.osDisk.osType",
          "equals": "Windows"
        },
        {
          "field": "Microsoft.Compute/licenseType",
          "notEquals": "Windows_Server"
        }
      ]
    },
    "then": {
      "effect": "audit"
    }
  }
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated, Thank you!

Regards,
Logan

Comment: Is it what you have tried so far ? Is it giving you any error ?

Comment: I tried lot of different conditions but none of them are working. Ex added  “not like Linux os” exclusively, allOf condition for both os types but no luck. As I said it’s working and reporting perfectly but the issue is Linux vm also coming as complaint.

Comment: so you want to report on osType = windows and licentype = ?

Comment: `"field": "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/licenseType"` should work.

Comment: I think i haven't explained it well. I have a policy which will report if the windows VMs are Azure hybrid enabled or not. If it's enabled it's showing as Compliant and if not then it's Non-Compliant. 

Now the issue is, Linux machines also reporting as Compliant which is creating a confusion and not able to work properly on the Compliance level.

Note: The licensetype field is already included in the policy and it's not working properly

Comment: @Thomas, Did you get a chance to look into this one?

Answer (score 0):

I have used AuditIfnotexist effect and then it started working.